# Xamarin.Mac NSThread.Start() stack overflow

Tags: c#, macos, mono, xamarin

I've got a rather complex Xamarin.Mac application. In fact, it's a windows forms application, but we're using Mono for Mac compatibility with a native Mac GUI. One of our business logic components involves watching the filesystem for changes using FSWatcher. Unfortunately, FSWatcher on Mac is horribly broken, leaving us to use the native FSEvents API via Xamarin.Mac.

Deep down in business logic, I've got a custom class called CBFileSystemWatcher which wraps the .NET FSWatcher, and on mac provides an adapter between the FSWatcher-expecting business logic and FSEvents on mac. INSIDE this compatibility class, I've got

```
private FSEventStream eventStream;
//...
this.eventStream.ScheduleWithRunLoop (NSRunLoop.Main);
```

which schedules the filesystem events on the main run loop. Unfortunately, this means the GUI blocks FS event handling, so suddenly if a modal dialog is open, for example, fs events stop getting processed.

My thought is to create a new runloop for the FS event scheduling, which I figure looks like

```
NSThread.Start(()=>{
    // Some other code
    this.eventStream.ScheduleWithRunLoop (NSRunLoop.Current);
});
```

**The snag is**, I think, that this code runs inside maybe two other layers of thread starts. For testing purposes, I've got the following code where I NEED the above code:

```
NSThread.Start(()=>{
    int i = 0;
});
```

with a breakpoint on the middle line to determine whether it was hit. 9 times out of ten I get the following stack overflow:

```
Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x261ba35, fault addr: 0xb02174d0
Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x261ba35, fault addr: 0xb02174d0
```

(the addresses change, though often recur)
**One time out of ten the code works exactly as expected and I break on i=0**

To test this further, I placed the above test inside my main AppDelegate.cs `FinishedLaunching` method. There, the code reliably works.

To further confuse matters, I placed the following code at the start of `FinishedLaunching`:

```
var fooThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    var barThread = new Thread(()=>{
        NSThread.Start(() =>
        {
            int i = 4;
        });
    });
    barThread.Start();
});
fooThread.Start();
```

With breakpoints on `fooThread.Start();`, `barThread.Start();`, and `int i = 4;` the code works exactly as expected, where the points are hit in reverse order.

My question is, does anyone have any ideas on how to even begin deubgging this? The SO is so out of the blue I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

A year later, I have this answer for you:

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37451/more-modal-problems-nsmenu-nsstatusitem